# If I truly repented for a major sin I had once committed, will it still show up in my records on Judgement Day?

Tags: sin, tawba, forgiveness, day-of-judgement

Let’s pretend I do a major sin and then inshallah do a perfect taubah and never do that sin ever again.

**Will it still show up in my records on Judgement Day?**

Comment: Please use a meaningful title that is clearly in relation to your question content.

Answer (score 0):

Allah is merciful, just be honest and ask for forgiveness. If Allah forgives you wont see about in afterlife, if not you will. Be hopeful on Allah's mercy.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

According to following verse of Quran none of the evil deeds will be left in the record

> And the record [of deeds] will be placed [open], and you will see the
> criminals fearful of that within it, and they will say, "Oh, woe to
> us! What is this book that leaves nothing small or great except that
> it has enumerated it?" And they will find what they did present
> [before them]. And your Lord does injustice to no one.
>
> <sup>[Quran, 18:49](https://legacy.quran.com/18/49)</sup>

Also, according to Quran, the record will show the good deeds as well, big or small, which  means that every tawba that a servant made also will be visible in the record, because tawba too is a good deed.

> 6.That Day, the people will depart separated [into categories] to be shown [the result of] their deeds. 7.So whoever does an **atom's
> weight of good will see it**, 8.And whoever does an **atom's weight of
> evil will see it**.
>
> <sup>[Quran, 99](https://legacy.quran.com/99)</sup>

Conclusion is that every sinful deed (big or small), every good deed (big or small), including repentances a servant did in his/her life, all of them, will show up in the record.

Answer (score -2):

Once you make sincere taubah that sin will be erased Allah knows best

Comment: Please provide facts and references that support your answer.